# Not able to establish SS connection using service connection in azure

Tags: azure, ssh, connection, cloud

I am generating the private key using puttygen and passing it to service connection which in turn tries to connect to linux remote machine.

When i run the pipe line i get below error:

> 2020-07-03T09:24:37.9310331Z ##[error]Failed to connect to remote
> machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Error:
> Cannot parse privateKey: PPK private key integrity check failed.

Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance.